# fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found #include_next <wchar.h> . error with visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, clang

I keep getting errors in VSC on programs which work in my IDE Clion. I now tried building a simple program and it still causes errors. Using Mac.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 

  'wchar.h' file not found
 #include_next <wchar.h>

 1 error generated.
 The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

code hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello, " << name;
    cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

This doesn't build. but the executable file hello works as intended. when I try to build with clang it throws this error.
when I try to use the command `g++ hello.cpp` in terminal, it gives this error:

```
ld: can't write output file: a.out for architecture x86_64
```

clang:

```
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The program is correct (https://godbolt.org/z/8KHcG9), so it is the configuration of your IDE/compiler